# combine text in sql i think?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the following SQL statement shown below. I do not get anything returned for the "image_link" in this line of code

```
,  'http://www.thesite.com/v/vspfiles/photos/' + IsNull(p.Vendor_PartNo,p.ProductCode) + '-2.jpg' AS image_link
```

If I change this line to the following (removing the "." in -2.jpg) then I get returned the complete link (prefix and suffix with ) but obviously without the "."

```
,  'http://www.thesite.com/v/vspfiles/photos/' + IsNull(p.Vendor_PartNo,p.ProductCode) + '-2jpg' AS image_link
```

What is wrong and how can I include the "." in the suffix?

```
SELECT p.ProductCode AS id
    ,  p.ProductName AS title
    ,  'Home & Garden > Household Appliance Accessories > Laundry Appliance Accessories' AS product_type
    ,  IsNull(pe.SalePrice,pe.ProductPrice) AS price
    ,  IsNull(pe.ProductManufacturer,'n/a') AS brand
    ,  IsNull(pe.ProductCondition,'new') AS condition
    ,  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (GETDATE() + 30),120) AS expiration_date
    ,  pd.ProductDescriptionShort AS [stripHTML-description]
    ,  'http://www.thesite.com/v/vspfiles/photos/' + IsNull(p.Vendor_PartNo,p.ProductCode) + '-2.jpg' AS image_link
    ,  'http://www.thesite.asp?ProductCode=' + p.ProductCode + '&Click=1327'  AS link
    , CAST(pe.ProductWeight AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' lb' AS weight
 FROM Products p
 JOIN Products_Descriptions pd ON p.ProductID = pd.ProductID
 JOIN Products_Extended pe ON pd.ProductID = pe.ProductID
WHERE (p.IsChildOfProductCode is NULL OR p.IsChildOfProductCode = ' 
       AND (p.HideProduct is NULL OR p.HideProduct <> 'Y')
  AND pe.ProductPrice > 0
ORDER BY p.ProductCode
```

Comment: string concatenation varies by vendor.  What database are you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite3, Oracle, MS SQL Server?

Comment: I believe the server is MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

In SQL-Server (Microsoft), simply use the + sign and char(46) to get the period

```
'http://www.thesiste/v/vspfiles/photos/'+
    isNull(p.vendor_partno,p.productCode)+'-2'+char(46)+'jpg'
```

See if the http: is causing the issue, perhaps the server is treating the link differently

```
'ht'+'tp://www.thesiste/v/vspfiles/photos/'+
    isNull(p.vendor_partno,p.productCode)+'-2'+char(46)+'jpg'
```

Could also try

```
replace('http:||www.thesiste|v|vspfiles|photos|','|','/')+
    isNull(p.vendor_partNo,p.productCode)+'-2'+char(46)+'jpg'
```

in case the slash character is causing a problem

It appears the slash character is being treated special.    Try creating a variable with the beginning value and use that...

```
DECLARE @URL varchar(200)
SET @Url = 'http://www.thesiste/v/vspfiles/photos/'

    @url + isNull(p.vendor_partno,p.productCode)+'-2'+char(46)+'jpg'
```

Or even, worse try,

```
    'http:'+char(47)+char(47)+'www.thesiste'+char(47)+'v'+char(47)+'vspfiles'+
char(47)+'photos'+char(47)'+
        isNull(p.vendor_partno,p.productCode)+'-2'+char(46)+'jpg'
```

Comment: That's what I originally had which doesn't work as shown above.

Comment: Confirm your version of SQL, I just ran this in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and it worked as expected...

Comment: not sure how to confirm that. When I put this in isNull(p.vendor_partno,p.productCode)+'-2'+char(46)+'jpg' AS image_link by itself i get a response with the suffix 00-7225-2.jpg but obviously not the prefix. Its just not working with the complete line of code. :(

Comment: I wonder if the server sees a link and tries to treat it differently.  Try the modified query above, breaking the URL format apart...

Comment: I tried all three but no go. Funny thing is if I remove all the "/" in the link it will show the link without the "/" and the rest of the it as well. I end up with a response of http:www.thesistevvspfilesphotos00-6190-2.jpg

Comment: what really makes no sense is next line with the link works fine as is.

Comment: it it possible the server can block a string or word? cause this works completely ,  'http://www.thesiste/v/vspfiles/photo'+p.ProductCode+'-2.jpg' AS image_link It seems that it is blocking the word "photos"

Comment: It is hard to say without knowing which version of SQL you are using. Can you run select @@VERSION (works for Microsoft SQL)...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3335/discussion-between-sparky-and-user357034)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
CONCAT('http://www.thesite.com/v/vspfiles/photos/', IsNull(p.Vendor_PartNo,p.ProductCode),'-2.jpg') AS image_link
```

Comment: yes just now... with this error CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Thx but I really don't know for sure that is why I stated "i believe" Sorry if I misled you.

Comment: but what about + '-2\.jpg' ? maybe the dot is treated as a special character for some reason then.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but off the top of my head, do you think you are having a data type problem?

```
'http://www.thesite.com/v/vspfiles/photos/' + Cast(IsNull(p.Vendor_PartNo,p.ProductCode) AS varchar) + '-2.jpg' AS image_link
```

Comment: thx but not working. :( just cannot understand why I can't combine the two strings

Comment: Just out of curiosity, was the cast function recognized?